# Which datastructure should I use in Redis for a notification system?

Tags: redis

I am trying to make a notification system with Redis rather than using MySQL which is what I use for the rest of the system. The reason for this is that I don't really need to save that much data so it can be saved in memory and I want it to be lightweight and fast.

The notifications will be kept temporarily. What I mean by that is that I do not want to save all notifications, but more like 50 latest unseen notifications for each user. So first thing I thought about was to use a linked list with a capped length of 50.

I would need to save this information for the notification:

```
postId
commentId
type
time
userId
username
image
```

So perhaps a JSON serialized string like this:

```
{"postId":1,"commentId":10,"type":1,"time":1462960058,"userId":2,"username":"Alexander","image":"ntfpRrgx.png"}
```

The notifications would be output like this on the client side:

```
Alexander commented on your post.
Alexander replied to your comment.
```

Where the type determines what kind of notification it is. I can handle "type" checks client side and output notification format accordingly. But here is the part I am having difficult with.

1) I need to be able to save the notifications in an ordered way so that I know which notification is newest.

2) I need to be able to know when a notification has been seen, so that it is not registered as not seen anymore.

3) I need to have a count of unseen notifications that I can show to the user. And If the user clicks on a notification, I need to mark that as a seen notification and decrement the count of unseen notifications.

4) I need to be able to mark all notifications as marked seen if the user wishes to do that.

5) I need to be able to get a subset of the notifications, whether seen or unseen, like an offset and limit on MySQL. For example, the user sees the newest 5 notifications, but he could click a next button and see the next 5, and the next 5 and so on.

I have no idea how to do all of this on Redis.

The key for the list or set could be `user:1:notification`. I know a list is sorted, and we can add and remove from the head and tail. But how do I achieve all these points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: You can use redis sorted sets (zset) operations and use timestamp as a score, and event id (or the entire event json) as a member.

ZADD my-set-key timestamp event-id

Then to get a page newest items you use zrevrange command. If you choose to use event id as a member, then you need additional structure to store event fields. I would recommend HSET eventid, field, value.

2: You can remove an item by member (event-id)

ZREM my-set-key event-id

3: Assuming your zset only keeps unseen, then you can use ZCARD to get size of the set

ZCARD my-set-key

4: You can remove an entire set in one shot using

DELETE my-set-key

5: You can paginate using zrange/zrevrange:

ZREVRANGE my-set-key start-position to-position

If you need to keep both seen and unseen items, then you need an extra zset where you only add, but don't remove once an item is seen

Comment: So if I understand correctly I should only save some eventIds in the zset, and then use hset to save the information about the event? How would I efficiently get all events with their information? In MySQL I would just do a join, but it is not possible here. I don't know how to best fetch the results by combining two data structures. zset and hset, where zset keeys the Ids and hset keeps the information.

Comment: As far I understand you only need to display details one page at a time. So no more than page size lookups are needed at a time. (You can read entire event hashes in one request). Redis is very fast at lookups as it gets them from memory. If it is still a problem for you (e.g. You want to minimize network round trips), you can again store the entire even blob (as json). Or you can store event fields from all events in a single key, as hset event-data-key event-id:field value. That way you can bulk read all values for the given page of event ids with one request.

Comment: I understand how to read all events in one request (one round trip) only if I have the whole json as the key in the sorted set. But if I only have the eventId as the key in the sorted set, and the event information in this way: hset eventId data "{ .... json structure}", or hset eventId fields... names... ++, then I have no idea how to fetch all notifications in correct order with their respective data from the hset in one single request, since redis cannot do JOINS like MySQL.

Comment: See my comment above. You can read multiple hash name/values at a time as long as they belong to the same hash map. Basically you concatenate your event-id with a field to make a hash key and store everything in the single my-data-key:  HSET {my-data-key}  {event-id}:{field} {value}, you can use then HMGET (http://redis.io/commands/hmget) to read multiple event-id/fields pairs at a time.

Comment: How can I limit the amount of notifications? With capping the sorted set length, or use some kind of time to live on the items on the sorted set, is it possible?

Comment: simple: before you ZADD a new event when zset is at your limit, remove the oldest entry, which you can get by ZRANGEBYSCORE with limit 1